Selenium Chrome can't disable the "save as" dialog
I upgraded my chrome driver version from 115 to 123.0.6312.106 yesterday and my testcase start to drop. A lot of my test cases need to download an .xls or .xlsx file and compare it to the file that i preset. But ever since i upgraded the driver, when it comes to the download step, the "save as" dialogue pops up, and it never shows up when i'm using version 115. So my question is how do I disable the "save as" dialogue.
Here is the function that start the chrome driver:
def get_new_driver(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """This method overrides get_new_driver() from BaseCase."""
    if not os.path.isdir(f'{get_project_path()}\\download_tmp\\{self.test_id}'):
        os.mkdir(f'{get_project_path()}\\download_tmp\\{self.test_id}')

    if get_browser_type() == 'chrome':
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-3d-apis")
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('detach', False)
        options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
        options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

        prefs = {
            "credentials_enable_service": False,
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 0,
            'download.default_directory': rf'{get_project_path()}\download_tmp\{self.test_id}',
            # "download.directory_upgrade": True,
            # "download.prompt_for_download": True,
            # "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
            # "download.extensions_to_open": "xlsx",
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.delete_all_cookies()

        return driver

I have tried some prefs I found on stack overflow, but none of them work.
I need to disable the "save as" dialog, so my test cases can successfully download file

run a quick check to see if the directory you are setting exists, then create it if it does not.  If it does not exist when you launch Chrome the pref won't be set.
